# PHP LDAP - get internal fields

Tags: php, ldap

I have a LDAP system already in place that has some internal fields such as entryUUID. Is there anyway to retrieve the value of the fields as currently

```
$filter = "(mail=".$email.")";

$result = ldap_search($client_LDAP->client_ldap_connection, $base_dc, $filter);
$info = ldap_get_entries($client_LDAP->client_ldap_connection, $result);
```

doesn't display them only retrieves the main data  (cn, ou, name, email ...etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve them using '+' as attribute-name.

So you should be able to fetch them using `ldap_search($client_LDAP->client_ldap_connection, $base_dc, $filter, ['+']);`

Note  that this will *only* retrieve the internal entries as no other attributes are defined within that last parameter to `ldap_search`.

Comment: We can get *all* attributes using `['*', '+']` : 
`*` returns all user attributes and `+` returns all internal attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to retrieve **all** attributes :

```
ldap_search($client_LDAP->client_ldap_connection, $base_dc, $filter, ['*', '+']);
```

`*` returns all user attributes and `+` returns all internal attributes.